# What is the purpose of a ModelLocator Singleton in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, singleton

The use I have for it is for storing user credentials, and calling a transfer object that functions as a sort of "cache" for the current session in all of the flex modules.

Thinking about objects that have to be present in every module. Is there any alternative to a singleton instance for this?

Comment: A user class as a Singleton is a perfect example for it. Why would you not want to use this?

Comment: because singletons are pathological liars.

Comment: Only if you understand how to set them up correctly. That article exaggerates some bad practices and then builds on them. Good OOP practices would never do what the author describes. Don't believe everything yeah read on the net.

Comment: You know, I've never met a coder who made the leap to completely eliminating Singletons from their code who said "You know, Singletons are great and they made my life SO easy.  I think I'll start using them again."  I read somewhere that the GoF heartily wished they had never included Singleton ins Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software.  But they did, and so now too many people use that pattern to _avoid_ learning good OOP practice.  Singleton is a throwback to procedural programming, and is in no way good OO practice.

Comment: The singleton we use contains mainly session and config data (webservice addresses), which I think are not that bad as singleton classes (although, the instantiation in every module smells everywhere). But then I added this cache class, that is only a getter, setter class of arraycollections. This bothers me. Then I started to look for workarounds for this. Because I really need to store data for general access in the application. This is dropdownlist data that should be loaded into the app only once. Thanks for the links! So useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Automated dependency injection frameworks, such as Mate, Robotlegs, Parsley, or Swiz.  Check out http://www.developria.com/2010/06/robotlegs-for-framework-beginn.html and http://www.developria.com/2010/05/mate-for-framework-beginners.html for a more in-depth look about how two of these work.

For just a few reasons you should avoid Singletons, see http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars